# VS code multiple formatting plugins issue (User Setting)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to understand why I am not able to specify an extension for formatting Json in VSCode. It gives an error: "Expected comma jsonc(514)" for " "code-runner.executorMap": { ". I have multiple plugins for Json and I am trying to configure one of the plugin by clicking on it but it says there is a problem in user setting. Thank you!

```
        "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
        "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
        "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
        "output.smartScroll.enabled": false,
        "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
        "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
        "c-cpp-flylint.flexelint.enable": false,
        "window.zoomLevel": 0,
        "java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false,
        "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
        "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
        "code-runner.executorMap": {
            "javascript": "node",
            "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
            "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "php": "php",
            "python": "python -u",
            "perl": "perl",
            "perl6": "perl6",
            "ruby": "ruby",
            "go": "go run",
            "lua": "lua",
            "groovy": "groovy",
            "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
            "bat": "cmd /c",
            "shellscript": "bash",
            "fsharp": "fsi",
            "csharp": "cd $dir && dotnet run $fileName",
            "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
            "typescript": "ts-node",
            "coffeescript": "coffee",
            "scala": "scala",
            "swift": "swift",
            "julia": "julia",
            "crystal": "crystal",
            "ocaml": "ocaml",
            "r": "Rscript",
            "applescript": "osascript",
            "clojure": "lein exec",
            "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
            "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "racket": "racket",
            "scheme": "csi -script",
            "ahk": "autohotkey",
            "autoit": "autoit3",
            "dart": "dart",
            "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "haskell": "runhaskell",
            "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
            "lisp": "sbcl --script",
            "kit": "kitc --run",
            "v": "v run",
            "sass": "sass --style expanded",
            "scss": "scss --style expanded",
            "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
            "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
            "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

needs a comma at the end.  In general, for this kind of error copy and paste your code into an online json linter, like `https://jsonlint.com` for better info where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, right after "true" put a ',' (coma) there like this

"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"code-runner.executorMap": {

The error will go, I also have the same error but after putting a coma there the error is corrected.